# Binding EasyMotion in Vim Visual Mode

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

What lines should I have in `.vimrc` to be able to use easymotion in visual mode? Currently I have these lines, but it isn't working:

```
nmap <C-N> <Plug>(easymotion-overwin-f)
vmap <C-n> <Plug>(easymotion-overwin-f)
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I am not using easymotion but did you unmap the default behaviour of

```
<C-N>
<C-n>
```

or used unmapped keys? The syntax seems correct.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. By using:

```
map <C-n> <Plug>(easymotion-bd-f)
nmap <C-n> <Plug>(easymotion-overwin-f)
```

…it works perfectly.